# PHP array keys - how to display?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm doing some work with a Google Analytics class. I get output as below:

```
Array
(
    [20090401] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 5000
            [ga:visits] => 2500
        )

    [20090402] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 5000
            [ga:visits] => 2500
        )
```

etc. How do I get the data to display in a table with the first column showing the date? ie the key for each array element.

like this:

> 20090401-----5000-----2500

Comment: foreach($report as $item)
{       $k=key($item)
 $pv=$item['ga:pageviews'];
 $vis=$item['ga:visits'];
}

$k always stores the same value - never changes.

Comment: $k always stores the same value, because $report never changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
foreach ($report as $date=>$item) {
  print($date.'-----'.$item['ga:pageviews'].'-----'.$item['ga:visits']);
}
?>
```

The piece you were missing was assigning the optional variable for the key in your `foreach`.

Comment: I assume you mean 
<code>
print($date.'-----'.$item['ga:pageviews'].'-----'.$item['ga:visits']);
</code>

Comment: Well, you'd format however you like with HTML or newlines. Sorry, this was just a skeleton example.

Comment: No, I meant that you had typed something else instead of $date.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I went back and fixed that when I noticed it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking but maybe this would help...

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . " => " . $value;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but here's the idea...

```
foreach ( $report as $item => $data ) {
  echo implode( '-----', array( $item, $data['ga:pageviews'], $data['ga:visits'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array AS $date => $data){
  echo '
<tr>
  <td>'.$date.'</td>
  <td>'.$data['ga:pageviews'].'</td>
  <td>'.$data['ga:visits'].'</td>
</tr>';
}
```

Check the php documentation about the [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct if you did not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function array_keys might help you out too: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php